# Link speed says 1Gbps but is actually only 100Mbps

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I've been transfering files across my network but seeing some things I don't understand.

When I view my network adapter Link speed it states that it is 1Gbps but when viewing the network details in the Resource Monitor, it says the max I/O speed is only 100Mbps.

After doing a couple of tests It does seem that I am being throttled at 100Mbps.  Why is this?  Why am I not getting the full 1Gbps bandwidth like the link speed on the network adapter says I should be getting?

and yes, I know the difference between bits and bytes...

Comment: Are you sure all network devices traversed can handle gigabit speeds?

Comment: Yeah, I am using an ASUS RT-AC68U router with a NETGEAR GS105 Gigabit switch.

Comment: (all connected with CAT6 cable)

Comment: Have you also checked that the other end of the transfer can handle gigabit speed? And you are sure you haven't got confused over bits per sec vs. bytes per sec?

Comment: please.. I know the difference between bits and bytes

Comment: *Please...* How are we supposed to know what you know? Asking simple questions helps rule out obvious issues or mistakes. Having an attitude is a great way to keep anyone from helping you.

Comment: That level of help is like saying "did you plug the PC into the power"

Comment: What network interface are you connecting from? If it's a motherboard on a PC, are you sure you're looking at the correct interface (some motherboards have multiple interfaces)? What tests did you run?

Comment: @JonCage Yes, definetly looking at the correct adapter.  Used a LAN speed test utlity. Measures Read/write speeds.  and I ran intances reading/writting to 2 different disks on the same machine simaltaniously.  But why would the adapter show Link speed of 1Gbps and the resource monitor show 100Mbps?

Comment: Reading / writing to disks as test isn't likely to be a good test of a gigabit link (most standard disks top out around the 40-50MB/s level).

Comment: Are you using any sort of virtualisation or firewall software?

Comment: No, It's disabled.

Comment: Are there any better ways to test network bandwidth?

Comment: Wikipedia has a few suggestions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_network_throughput#Bandwidth_test_software

Comment: My guess would be that something on your machine is adding a layer between your test software and the physical link which is slowing the connection. Where exactly are you seeing the 100Mbps figure?

Comment: In the resource monitor under network activity there are 2 stats, Network I/O and utilization. the I/O stat is the one that maxes out at 100Mbps.  Also, when it is maxed out at 100, everything else that requuires network bandwidth grinds to a halt speed wise.

Comment: What happens if you connect your computer directly to another computer with a crossover cable? Are the results the same or different in any way?

Comment: This seems like a stupid issue, but switch out the cable. Gigabit networking uses all 8 wires in a cat 5 cable and 10/100 only uses 4.

Comment: You mention you have a router and a switch, but how's the network topology between the systems you have tested with? There's bandwidth limiting functionality in the router at least, if it sits between the end points check those settings. Also bypassing both the router and the switch as @Twisty suggested would be a good idea. If you have more devices with gigabit ports testing also with those (and posting the results in the question) might also help. Please do update the question with the relevant details instead of putting them (only) in comments.